# Any tricks to enable Windows-11 backup compression?

Tags: backup, windows-11, windows-backup

I've setup backups of my desktop machine to the network drive ("File History"). Unlike Windows-7 backup utility, which I can no longer use, Windows-10 backup *does not compress* the data, which means, my virtual-disk images are going to eat up the space real fast.

Is there something I can still do to have my backups compressed somehow -- using the OS-provided components -- without adding 3rd-party code (or writing my own)?

Comment: You are better off using a 3rd party backup software, as all of them do compression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NTFS compression on shared folders:

1. Right click the shared folder where the backups are saved.
2. Select `Properties`
3. Click `Advanced...`
4. Select `Compress contents to save disk space`
5. OK OK

NOTE: I this option isn't available you would have to run this command from the fileserver:

```
fsutil behavior set DisableCompression 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for some client-based compression -- as it should be a lot more efficient... The network folder storing my backups is on a Unix-based NFS-appliance -- I have no access to it.

Comment: @MikhailT. if you are using a Unix based NFS appliance I would recommend using the OS level compression there. It will be transparent, easy, and it will affect everything not just backups. If you compress the archive and then store it on a compressed disk you won't see much improvement.

https://www.servethehome.com/the-case-for-using-zfs-compression/

Comment: For one, filesystem compression is not as efficient -- because it compresses blocks independently, instead of the entire files. More importantly, I have no control over the appliance :-)

Comment: Then use a backup software that supports this efficient compression you speak of. You asked for tricks and I gave you a trick. ZFS compression works great in my experience. Much better than NTFS compression from my original answer.

Comment: I cannot, unfortunately, install any software -- and must use the OS-components provided by Microsoft. Windows-7 backup component did allow compression, but with Windows-11 I cannot find that option...

Comment: That significantly reduces your options for "tricks". You should cite your restrictions in the original question but after this question sitting stale for 3 years, you should contact your systems administrator as they are the only ones that can help you.